# How do I use HttpURLConnection with RxJava?

Tags: java, rx-java, httpurlconnection

Here's a sample code of http request in Java:

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

What's the best way to *combine* `HttpURLConnection` and `RxJava`?

My current option is:

```
Observable.defer(() -> {
   return sendHttpRequest(); // uses HttpURLConnection and returns a response's content as a string
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45381841/how-to-make-a-http-request-to-check-a-content-type-with-rxjava-2

Comment: @VarunJain I did see that question but I'm not concerned about using main thread / I don't think using `.just()` is a good approach here.

Comment: No, just() method can be used in the way mentioned in the link in 1st comment. But I want to know why just() is not a good approach and what is basis of your saying because I haven't found anywhere mentioned like that!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52671715/10946826

Comment: Yeah, as the statement mentioned in the link, you are still free to use just or from as per your needs. So if you needs can be sufficed by lazily then you can use from otherwise just is also fine!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Callable`. I've already written an answer on how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71304587/11146632).

> ```
> java Observable.fromCallable((Callable<Object>) () -> {
>     // do stuff
>     return object;
> })
>         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
>         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
>         .subscribe(new Observer<Object>() {
>             @Override
>             public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
>                 // so that this can be properly disposed in onDestroy()
>                 compositeDisposable.add(d);
>             }
>
>             @Override
>             public void onNext(@NonNull Object object) {
>                 // do stuff with the result
>             }
>
>             @Override
>             public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
>             }
>
>             @Override
>             public void onComplete() {
>             }
>         });
> ```